# What is the difference between ng-minlength and minlength in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

What is the difference between ng-minlength and minlength

Comment: did you try to check documentation?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know.

1) It's a way to add min-length validation to the control without needing HTML 5 support

2) It adds the minlength validator to the ngmodel

Answer (score 0):

*ngMinlength* is "angular-aware" so you will put an expression as attribute value (instead of the value itself).
Using *ngMinLength* will allow AngularJs to include the constraint in its form validation system. Regular HTML5 minlength validation will not be performed.

@see : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMinlength

Answer (score 0):

> ngMinlength adds the minlength validator to ngModel.

The ng-minlength allows for example you to validate the input. You can for example show an custom error message accordingly like this:

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <form name="form">
    <label for="input">This input is minlength 4: </label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="model" id="input" name="input" ng-minlength="4" /><br>
    <span ng-if="form.input.$invalid" style="color:red">THE INPUT IS NOT VALID</span>
    <hr>
    input valid? = <code>{{form.input.$valid}}</code><br>
    model = <code>{{model}}</code>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also

> ngMinlength does not set the minlength attribute and therefore HTML5 constraint validation is not available.

Documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMinlength